# Kubernetes nvidia-gpu UnexpectedAdmissionError

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, nvidia

I have a k8s cluster with one master and one worker. Worker has GPUs, and I am able to schedule pods on it using GPUs.

I add the second worker, also with GPUs. Everything is properly installed on that second worker. When I try to schedule GPU busybox on that second worker I get status `UnexpectedAdmissionError`.

With `kubectl describe pod busybox` I see `Warning  UnexpectedAdmissionError  7m    kubelet, wikiserver  Update plugin resources failed due to requested number of devices unavailable for nvidia.com/gpu. Requested: 1, Available: 0, which is unexpected.` which is odd since with `kubectl describe nodes second-worker` I see that both Capacity and Allocatable are `nvidia.com/gpu: 1`

I was able to successfully schedule GPU busybox on first worker. Also, I was able to schedule CPU busybox on both workers.

This is yaml conf for GPU busybox:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
    resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 1 
  restartPolicy: Always
  nodeName: secondworker
```

The second worker (and first worker and the master) is configured as described by [nvidia-device-plugin](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin).

Comment: Have you tried running it without the limit? That should allocate all available GPUs to your system; then you can exec into the box and see if the GPUs are indeed all visible. It could be a node problem; you can also try recreating another node and see if that works.

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu the docs says to use the limits in the deployment.

Comment: Can you describe the node to check that the daemonset pod is indeed running. Have you tried restarting the node?